# How can I use nested includes with the Football API? (SOLVED)

Tags: nested, include

I'm trying to enrich my API response with includes using the [sportmonks.com](https://sportmonks.com) football API. Here is the documentation: https://sportmonks.com/docs/football/2.0/leagues/a/get-by-id/7

However, it seems like it doesn't work with my request:
https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/leagues/2?api_token=MYTOKEN&include=season&fixtures

How can I enrich this response with all the fixtures of a season?

I've solved the issue. Instead of season&fixtures, I should've used [season.fixtures](https://www.sportmonks.com/docs/football/2.0/getting-started/a/api-flexibility-and-relationships/88). Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: That documentation has code examples from a large number of languages. Which language are you trying to use this with?

Comment: Please, provide output of response, i.e. `curl https://soccer.sportmonks.com/api/v2.0/leagues/2?api_token=MYTOKEN&include=season&fixtures`

Comment: I'm using JSON. Response of my request: {"data":{"id":2,"active":true,"type":"cup_international","legacy_id":11,"country_id":41,"logo_path":"https:\/\/cdn.sportmonks.com\/images\/soccer\/leagues\/2.png","name":"Champions League","is_cup":true,"current_season_id":16029,"current_round_id":null,"current_stage_id":77443827,"live_standings":true,"coverage":},"season":{"data"{"id":16029,"name":"2019\/2020","league_id":2,"is_current_season":true,"current_round_id":null,"current_stage_id":77443827}}},